# Loading screen for iOS app

Tags: ios

I need a loading screen to show while some data is being downloaded from the server. I present a view controller with modal segue without animation. But I don't know how to dismiss the loading screen view controller since `dismissViewController` function can only be called from inside.

I should be able to dismiss the loading screen view controller from another view controller. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'd recommend using an NSNotification in this case, but you should be able to dismiss the view controller from another view controller.

Comment: This is a commonly used tool: https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `NSNotificationCenter`. You can post custom notification and listen it in loading view for closing it.

If you are getting the data in parent view then you can close the loading view from parent view also. You can call `dismissViewController` from parent view using [presentingViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/presentingViewController) property of `UIViewController` class.

In your case from parentView you can dismiss the child view using:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

> **presentingViewController**
>
> The view controller that presented this view controller. (read-only)
>   Declaration
>
> **Swift**
>
> `var presentingViewController: UIViewController? { get }`
>
> **Objective-C**
>
> ```
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) UIViewController *presentingViewController
> ```
>
> **Discussion**
>
> When you present a view controller modally (either explicitly or
>   implicitly) using the presentViewController:animated:completion:
>   method, the view controller that was presented has this property set
>   to the view controller that presented it. If the view controller was
>   not presented modally, but one of its ancestors was, this property
>   contains the view controller that presented the ancestor. If neither
>   the current view controller or any of its ancestors were presented
>   modally, the value in this property is nil. Import Statement
>
> import UIKit Availability
>
> Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to show another VC? You could just show a subview, making it visible=true when you start the app, and on the request success or failure callbacks hide it again (depending on the networking framework you are using)

I don't know were you start the request and were you know when it is done, if the loading screen knows when the download is finished you can do one of two things, or you pass the first VC as a delegate (defining a protocol) to the second VC (loading screen), and when you know on the loading screen that the download is finished you call a method on the delegate that will dismiss the loading screen,

Or you can use NSNotificationCenter, register for some kind of events on the first VC and when the process finishes on the loading screen you notify the first VC with this method, to dismiss the loading screen.

If you start the process on the first VC, and you know when it ends also on the first VC I would not understand your question, as you would just dismiss the loading screen and it would work.
Could you give more info? If you'd like I can post some code in order to help you in one of this approaches.